# Magnetic Field Vector from Uniform Current Density direction

Tags: electromagnetism

I tried solving Part (c) where it asks to sketch vectors representing the magnetic field $B$ at points $P_1$ and $P_2$ where there is an uncharged conducting slab with uniform current density $j$ directed out of the page.

I know that the magnetic field vector is perpendicular to the flow of the current, but I'm really confused why the magnetic field $B$ points to the left at $P_1$ and not to the right?

As for Part (d), if I draw a rectangular path such that the top and bottom parts with length $L$ pass through $P_1$ and $P_2$ respectively and the sides are of length 2a each, the $I$ in Ampere's Law would be $jA=j(2a)(L)$. But, why is the $\oint_C {Bd\ell}$ equal to $2BL$ and not $B*2(L+2a)$?

[image: This is the link to the prompt]
[image: This is the link to the answers]